# How can I run an ASP.net 4.0 app in the ISV folder on CRM 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

How can I run an ASP.net 4.0 app in the ISV folder on CRM 4.0?

It works if I make the asp.net app target .net 2.0, but if I switch it to .net 4.0 I get 404.17's.  Which imply that the script handler setting is missing from my web config, but isn't that built into the .net 4.0 runtime now?  (hence it's removal from the web.config automatically).

When my app was .net 2.0, I had modified the web config in the proper manner that is well documented on various sites and blogs on the net.

Anyone able to get this working?  (I need to use a .net 4 web control on my asp.net page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is going to be possible. [See here.](http://xrm.ascentium.com/blog/crm/Post834.aspx)

You CAN, however, create a new web app, but you won't be able to use all the ISV/CRMImpersonator Voodoo that is available when you run it in the ISV folder.

Comment: I thought since you have to create a new application in the isv folder to get your stuff working, it would be the same as created a new web app anyway?

Comment: What I meant by that was to create an entirely new web site.  From that same article: "If you want to use .NET 4.0 with CRM 4.0, you are not entirely out of luck. As long as it runs in its own process space, either on the client (like a Silverlight 4.0 control) or on another web site (like an IFRAME or a pop-up dialog from a CRM form), things should work just dandy"